# How does adding more coils to an AM tuner coil allow it to tune Shortwave?

Tags: rf, inductor, radio, coil, amplitude-modulation

I have seen several tutorials about how to turn an AM radio into a Shortwave radio.  They add more coils to the inductor (is that the correct name for the tuning coil?).

Here is one example,

https://www.instructables.com/id/Listen-to-Shortwave-Broadcasts-on-an-AM-Radio/

There are many.  Why does adding more coil make this medium wave AM all of a sudden be able to pick up Shortwave?

Comment: Change the frequency of the local oscillator, and the front end RF filter and hey presto - but getting the inductors to the correct values is going to be hit or miss without some specialised test equipment. Plus you’ll only have AM, and there’s not much interesting traffic using that mode today.

Comment: I recall owning a Hallicrafters S-38, which purportedly covered 0.54MHz to 30MHz. I doubt the 12BE6 oscillator-mixer provided much gain at 30MHz, what with all the parasitics.

Comment: How do you know how many turns or what gauge wire to use to lower the inductance?  If you lower it too much, it won't pick up anything, I gather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagrams show the new coil being added electrically in parallel to the existing coil.  This makes the total inductance lower.

The new coil has a very low inductance (very few loops.)  The existing coil has many loops.  Put in parallel, the total inductance is lower than that of the low inductance loop.

Lower inductance means it passes higher frequencies better.  Short wave radio is transmitted on much higher frequencies than regular AM radio.

Shortwave starts a little over 2MHz and goes up to around 30MHz.

Regular AM radio is between 530kHz and 1.6MHz.

So, when you put in the new, low inductance coil, you make the radio more receptive to higher frequencies.